# .NET, WMI - StdRegProv not found!

Tags: .net, wmi

Doing 
`ManagementObject obj = new ManagementObject(@"root\default:StdRegProv");`
**throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException**
as well as

```
ManagementClass regClass = new ManagementClass(new ManagementPath("StdRegProv"));
inParams= regClass.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue"); //throws ManagementException "Not found"
```

What the..????????????

Comment: what the question???????

Comment: Are you sure that path is correct? Isn't the \\MachineX\root\cimv2 the correct path?

Answer (score 1):

Thanx for your reply.
I've managed to get it correctly by coding like this:

```
ManagementScope sc = (ManagementScope)scope.Clone();
            sc.Path.NamespacePath = "root\\default"; //StdRegProv is in there
            ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\Default:StdRegProv", sc.Path.Server));
            regClass = new ManagementClass(sc, path, null);
```

Scope is initialized earlier like this

```
ConnectionOptions c = new ConnectionOptions();
            c.Username = "User";
            c.Password = "Password";
            c.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Default;
            string path = @"\\Myserver\root\cimv2";
            scope = new ManagementScope(path, c);
            scope.Connect();
```

//path is init to ...cimv2 b/c I use it for other objects too